# Three js : View to follow mouse movement of another scene

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, three.js

I am using three.js to create a equirectangular panorama.
I have a functionality where in I can split the view and create a duplicate of the original panaroma.
When I move the mouse and drag left/right on the original panaroma I want the duplicate panaroma to also move accordingly. 
Somewhat like the locked screen feature in holobuilder.
Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far? Show us your code. It should be as simple as assigning the same values from the camera of pano1 to the camera of pano2.

Comment: function renderSplit() {
  
    latSplit = Math.max(-85, Math.min(85, lat));
    phiSplit = THREE.Math.degToRad(90 - lat);
    thetaSplit = THREE.Math.degToRad(lon);
 
 targetSplit.x = 100 * Math.sin( phiSplit ) * Math.cos( thetaSplit );
    targetSplit.y = 100 * Math.cos( phiSplit );
    targetSplit.z = 100 * Math.sin( phiSplit ) * Math.sin( thetaSplit );
   cameraSplit.lookAt( targetSplit );
    rendererSplit.render(sceneSplit, cameraSplit);

Comment: I'm gonna need a little more than that. Where's the duplicate? You should try to apply the same method to the duplicate. What part of what you've tried is not working?